# Error when checking target: expected dense_49 to have shape (2943,) but got array with shape (1,)

Tags: keras, neural-network, artificial-intelligence, lstm

I'm  creating an LSTM that predicts next words for text generation, but I keep getting an error when trying to train the model

I've tried changing the dimensions of the input but that doesn't seem to work

```
X_train.shape
```

(32249, 5, 1)

```
y_train.shape
```

(32249,)

```
print(X_train[0])
```

[['opened'] ['for'] ['it.'] ['how'] ['they']]

```
model = Sequential()
model.add(Bidirectional(LSTM(128), input_shape=(5, 1)))
model.add(Dropout(0.2))
model.add(Dense(units = len(words)))
model.add(Activation('softmax'))
model.compile(optimizer="adam", loss="mean_squared_error")
```

```
model.fit(X_train, y_train, epochs=1)
```

ValueError: Error when checking target: expected activation_27 to have shape (2943,) but got array with shape (1,)

I've shown the code, and the results it gives. I keep getting this error ^

Comment: What are the contents of y_train? Class indices? In that case you have to one-hot encode them.

Comment: No, they are just strings of the next words

Comment: You still need to encode these as class indices, and then one-hot encode them.

Comment: Okay, I'll try that thnx

Comment: Thanks, that worked, didn't think of one-hot encoding, makes sense though

Comment: If you change the loss to "sparse_categorical_crossentropy" then you don't need to one-hot encode them, just use the vocabulary index, keras will do it automatically. But the loss will behave differently from MSE, it will punish using the log of the difference on the "true word", not the squarred error for each word in the voc :-)